# CSS selector that has nothing in them affecting my code

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm making media queries for a min-width of 930 px which is easy enough. My issue is that since I'm new, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this or that and changing margin padding etc in different places.

Eventually, I find out what the issue is but that leaves let's say a .top selector empty now since that wasn't the issue but now I can't delete that selector because it changes the way my CSS acts why is this??

```css
@media (min-width: 930px) {
      .hero-bg {
        text-align: left;
      }
      .top p {
        margin: 0 0em 2em;
      }
      .bottom
      .top{
      }
      .form-container{
        margin: 2em 0 0;
        padding: 0 em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
```

I'm trying to take out .top but when I do it has an effect on margin and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

because .top p affects the paragraph corresponding to the top.   remove the top and top p, and make .top p a separate class, then call the class where you want that margin

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```css
.bottom
.top { }
```

is not an empty selector, as it translates to `.bottom .top` and when you just take out the `.top` line, it will translate to `.bottom .form-container`

A truly empty selectors would look like this:

```css
.bottom { }     /* safe to take out */
.top { }        /* safe to take out */
.form-container { ... }
```